# Upload multiple containers to Azure Container registry

Tags: asp.net, azure, docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I have ASP.NET Core app, that is packed to docker.

Here is my docker-compose file, it has kibana and EL images in it.

```
  version: "3.1"

services:
  tooseeweb:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tooseewebcontainer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:80
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - docker-network

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - docker-network

networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
```

I try to deploy this to Azure Container Registry via this article
[Article link](https://www.dragonbe.com/2018/02/deploy-docker-containers-fast-to.html)

It's all okay and I see my APIб it's under 80 port. But I don't see kibana and elastic search.

At local machine I make `docker-compose up` and see it by `5601` and `9200`, but on Azure Container Registry this ports not working. How I can deploy all together? Or I need to deploy containers separately?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the Azure Container Registry store the docker images for you. So you need to push the images to it, not the running containers. And you do not need to separate them, but you need to create all the images with the name as your_acr_name.azurecr.io/image_name:tag and then push them to the ACR.

As I see in your question, you only create the image `tooseeweb` with the name `${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tooseewebcontainer`, when you push this image to the ACR, it only stores this one for you, does not contain the other two images.

If you want to store the other two images in ACR, you need to follow the two steps below.

1. tag your image. For example:

```
    docker tag docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4 your_acr_name.azurecr.io/elasticsearch:6.2.4
```

2. push the image to ACR.

```
    docker push your_acr_name.azurecr.io/elasticsearch:6.2.4
```

Comment: @EugeneSukh Well, let me know if you have more questions or accept it as the answer after a try.

Comment: @EugeneSukh Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's helped me